# gnuplot setup VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, gnuplot

Can't setup gnuplot in VS Code on Mac ('gnuplot.h' file not found).

```
Here are what I did:
1) installed gnuplot via brew;
2) also installed Gnuplot extension in VS Code;
3) opened VS Code Settings and searched for Gnuplot;
4) in the Gnuplot: Gnuplot Path specified the path;
5) restarted VS Code;
6) run program but still got an error 'gnuplot.h' file not found.

Could you please advise how to set it up?
Thanks!
```

[image]